# Reason for group formation timeout in Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I am using two Wi-Fi Direct enabled devices (Let be A with android ICS running  and B with Android Jelly Bean )

A has intent value 3 and B has intent value 5 . GO Negotiation happens and B elected as GO. I am using Wi-Fi DirectDemo App for file transfer and able to transfer file from A to B successfully.

Next I changed the intent value of A to 15 and B has intent value 5. GO negotiation happens and A elected as GO.It moves to Provisoning phase then. But the Group Formation fails with no error message except "Group Formation timeout"

Group formation failure happens due to

1) Failed WPS provisioning

2) 15 sec timeout.

Since no error messages are thrown it is hard to debug the issue.I have two queries.

1. What process actually takes place in this 15 secs.?
2. Is there any common reason or cause for this timeout?

Expecting answers from Wi-Fi Direct experts.......

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its EAPOL handshake failure. 
We need the sniffer traces to pin point the issue. If you got a sniffer, please share the capture

Comment: From the sniffer capture I was not able to find the EAPOL handshake is not all taking place. No further frames after GO Negotiation Confirmation frame.

Comment: Source           Destination    InfoMAC of A   MAC of B   Probe Response, SN=2004, FN=0, Flags=........, BI=100, SSID=DIRECT-
MAC of A   MAC of B Action, SN=2511, FN=0, Flags=........, P2P - GO Negotiation Request
MAC of A   MAC of B Action, SN=2511, FN=0, Flags=....R..., P2P - GO Negotiation Request
MAC of B  MAC of A  Action, SN=1705, FN=0, Flags=........, P2P - GO Negotiation Response
MAC of A   MAC of B Action, SN=2514, FN=0, Flags=........, P2P - GO Negotiation Confirmation

Comment: Sorry for the above messed up sniffer capture...not able to edit it

Comment: How the EAPOL key exchange is initiated....I have a hostpad.conf file with EAPOL related stuffs enabled......

Comment: I analysed the GO Negotiation confirmation frame of working and non working case. The P2P GROUP ID attribute of working case has ssid field value DIRECT-xy-Android_6fde but in non working case it is just the Wildcard ssid and some random value always ( DIRECT-LO).  Is there any chance for the client searching a wrong ssid (DIRECT-LO) and moving to timeout .? .As I am able to see only probe request frames from client side and GO responding with no probe response frames after the GO negotiation confirmation frame.